# How to reclaim CTR+ALT+Down/Up for use in xorg apps?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, xorg, xfce

I am using the XFCE desktop and I would like to be able to use <kbd>CTR</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>/<kbd>Up</kbd> in an application (Eclipse) that has this shortcut defined by default for an action I use often.

As far as I understand XFCE and other window managers reserve the <kbd>CTR</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>/<kbd>Up</kbd> key combination for switching between virtual desktops and therefore it is not available to normal apps. Or is it xorg that binds this combination?

I have looked through all the XFCE settings hoping to find where it is defined so that I could undefine it and use it in Eclipse but did not find anything useful. Not sure it is an XFCE issue at all since all the other popular window managers appear to 'suffer' from the same issue.

In which config file is this shortcut defined and how can I undefine it so that it can be used in applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to **Settings » Window Manager » Keyboard** and unbind `Upper Workspace` and `Lower Workspace`

I did the same for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and Netbeans.